# In Jmeter, I am getting error like "no such window: target window already closed" and "timeout exception" using selenium webdriver sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am going open the login url and find elements doing the login things...
1)I have total windows only 1.there is no any other windows. But i am getting exception like no window exception in selenium webdriver sampler

2)Also I am getting the Timeout exception: like expected wait condition (waiting for element tobeclickable()) is failed

Expected results

1. fix no windows error
2. timeout exception using selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to help you without seeing:

1. Your script
2. The [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) of the page you're trying to test

With regards to errors:

1. [NoSuchWindowException](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchWindowException.html) occurs when WebDriver cannot find window or tab with the given handle or name so inspect your code and remove any [WebDriver.switchTo()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo()) function calls
2. Timeout on wait can occur:

   - if the element is not present in the DOM, call [WebDriver.getPageSource()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()) on failure and ensure that it's there
   - your [element locator](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) doesn't match anything in the page, revisit it and ensure that it matches anything and the match is the only one you're looking for

Also if you're using JSR223 Sampler and initializing the WebDriver manually it might be the case you're doing it in not a [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) manner so one virtual user can try controlling the browser instance which was invoked by another user. Consider switching to WebDriver Sampler which provides isolation of the browser processes and simplifies browser configuration and WebDriver instantiation, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do thread-safe manner in jsr223 sampler